# Can't access SQLite database stored within file structure of WPF application namespace (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am creating a WPF app using Visual Studio and am wanting to store a database within the projects "Assets" folder in order to make the app fully self contained.

I created the database externally (didn't use migrations or equivalent coded constructs which I have seen done) and have tried to access the database through a path similar to what I used to access the images also stored within the "Assets" folder `Assets\data\database.db` however the program then throws an error when I try and access the database saying that it cannot be found.

**Database access**

```
namespace Project
{
    public class LoadDb
    {
        public LoadDb()
        {
            ReadDatabase();
        }

        void ReadDatabase()
        {

            using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=..\Assets\data\database.db"))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand("Select * from Data", conn);
                SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                var dataList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("dataId")), reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"))));
                }
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
                

        }
    }
}
```

Changing `@"Data Source=C:\(full path)\Assets\data\database.db"` does work however that path is dependent on the location of the app which I didn't think was what I was wanting.

I am very new to WPF and C# so have been learning from various tutorials and forums but nothing I can find has anything similar to what I am wanting, I have seen storage within `C:\ProgramData\` but (unless I am thinking incorrectly) that wouldn't be a self contained application?

----Edit----

This is a screenshot of the file structure within the project namespace within Visual Studio.
[image: file layout]

Comment: Have you tried `.\Assets\data\database.db` with a single dot at the front?

Comment: `.` means start at the location of the directory that houses the app's .exe, `..` means its starting at the folder above it. For this reason the path is breaking on the search for the `Assets` directory, as its not present in the folder above the exe's home

Comment: I have tried using the suitable number of `.`  to get from the .exe to the application folder but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your `Assets` folder near your application *.exe file, the following code will fix the issue. (Tested - it connects to the database.)

```
void ReadDatabase()
{
    string appFolder = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string dbFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appFolder, "Assets\\data\\database.db");
    string connectionString = $"Data Source={dbFilePath}";
    using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        // Other stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: This works only when the files are within the same folder as the .exe . Within the WPF project the .exe is within `<Project namespace>\bin\debug\net6.0-windows10.0.22621.0\ ` whereas the .xaml, .cs, and Assets folder are within the project namespace folder (see image added to question). How do I access the folder without having to move it to the same folder that contains the .exe?

Comment: Create the `Assets\data\database.db` file (with this hierarchy) under your WPF project in Visual Studio. Then right click `database.db` and click Properties. Set Build Action to *Content* and Copy to Output Directory as *Copy if newer*. This way when you build the project then the `database.db` file will automatically copied to the output folder that you specify above.

Comment: You are on the right track. Did you set the Build Action and Copy to Output Directory values as I just point out?

Comment: Works beautifully!

Comment: Glad to see that it works.